# Tangent spheres in a square: generalization to arbitrary dimension

Tags: geometry

I found this simple geometry problem:

in a square trace the circumference tangent to the 4 sides and another tangent to the first and two sides (see the link).

Known the radius R of the major circumference find the radius r of the minor one

it's easy to get to r = $R(3-2\sqrt{2})$

I'd be curious to know:
1) if we pass from the square to the cube and from circumference to the sphere, how much does $r$ become?
2) if we switch to the hypercube and hypersphere in 4d?
3) is there a series?

I have read people claim that $r=R\frac{\sqrt{n}-1}{\sqrt{n}+1}$, where $n$
is the dimension, but I do not see why in going from 2D to 3D one cannot take the 2D section of the 3D problem and claim that the solution is the same as in 2D.
Have a nice day![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jckw.jpg

Comment: I think I got it. In 3D the segment OM will be for example computed by the 3D version of Pythagora theorem with two contributions coming from length and width dimensions and one from the height dimension. What I was missing is the fact that the small sphere in 3D will be close to a corner of the cube, whereas I was depicting it in the middle of one of cube's sides.